# Android cannot resolve symbol R after system freeze and restart

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My laptop froze while Android Studio was building so I restarted it. After that a file was completely erased, which I recovered by reverting a version from local history buy I am still facing a couple of issues.

One of them is the above -

> Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'app:windowActivityTransitions'.
>
> Error:(4, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'app:windowEnterTransition'.
>
> Error:(4, 5)
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'app:windowExitTransition'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/home/vineet/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

This arises in my `style.xml` file. Here it is. The lines with the error are the final three lines in `AppTheme`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
        <item name="windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="colorControlNormal">#E0E0E0</item>-->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

The other is :

> cannot resolve symbol `R`

I have tried clean building/ re-building/ android studio restart and even system restart.

Please help!

**EDIT**

I commented the three window transition items in `AppTheme`. That somehow resolves `the cannot find symbol R` error. How do I use those transition lines without getting the `R` error again?

Comment: If you uncomment it again the problem gets back?

Comment: Yes, removing comment causes the error to reappear.

Comment: For the second error: if Android Studio cannot compile resources, there will be no `R` class generated. That is expected.

Comment: Which API level do you compile it with? Transitions require API ≥ 21.

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 23 in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Comment: I resolved the error myself. Posted it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out in the comments, R couldn't be resolved because resources weren't getting compiled.

As for the first error in the question ie. the transition properties,
setting the `minSdkVersion` in the manifest resolves it. I had set it to 21 in `build.gradle` but for some reason it only worked after I specified it in `manifest.xml`.